# Mostrar todos los números primos menores a N numero ingresado por el usuario en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, números-primos

Según el enunciado me pide mostrar los números primos menores al numero que ingreso el usuario

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
function esPrimo(numero) {
    
    for(let i = 2,raiz=Math.sqrt(numero); i <= raiz; i++)
        if(numero % i === 0) return false;
    return numero > 1;
}
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
    if (esPrimo(i))
        document.write("El número " + i + " es primo <br>");
}
let n = parseInt(prompt("Cantidad de elementos del arreglo"));
esPrimo(n);
```

Pero al momento de ingresar la cantidad no me arroja ningún resultado :(

Comment: el `let n = ....` va arriba del `for`. Daría la sensación de que no hiciste ese código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice este pequeño algoritmo. Luego lo puedes implementar en cualquier lenguaje.

```
Algoritmo Primos
Escribir "Escribe un numero para saber los primos menores"
Leer numeroPrimos;

numeroComprobar<-2
numeroDivisor<-2
esPrimo = Verdadero

 Mientras numeroComprobar < numeroPrimos Hacer  
    
    Si numeroDivisor < numeroComprobar y numeroComprobar%numeroDivisor == 0 Entonces    
        esPrimo = Falso
    FinSi
    
    Si  numeroDivisor < numeroComprobar  y esPrimo
        numeroDivisor = numeroDivisor+1;
    SiNo
        Si esPrimo
            Escribir "Numero primo: ",numeroComprobar
        FinSi
        
        numeroDivisor = 2;  
        numeroComprobar = numeroComprobar+1;
        esPrimo = Verdadero
    Fin Si
 Fin Mientras
FinAlgoritmo
```

Esa sería la solución a tu problema.